# MagicZoomPlus zoomed image positioning

Tags: javascript, css, magiczoomplus

I use MagicZoomPlus as a module in PrestaShop.
but the zoom image is not shown in correct position.
take a look at following URL:
http://beheshtian.org/product.php?id_product=11

how can I fix this?

(when you move your mouse on thumbnail, the zoom image is not in correct position, move to the very left and very right and you'll see the problem)

Comment: what "position" do you want it to show in? Need more details

Comment: when you move your mouse on thumbnail, the zoom image is not in correct position, move to the very left and very right and you'll see the problem

Answer (score 0):

Makes sure that the Zoom image is the same ratio as your main image for example if your main product image is 600x150 (a ratio of 4:1) then your zoom image needs to have the same ratio 1200x300 (4:1).